# Do any of the Babylon 5 cultures use matter/antimatter power sources?

Tags: babylon-5

To my knowledge and memory, I don't recall humans or aliens (with the exception of the invaders from the tv-movie Thirdspace) on Babylon 5 making use of force fields or deflector shields so I don't see how they could safely contain antimatter for use as a power source- has this ever been discussed or mentioned on the series?

Comment: Ulkesh appeared to have a force field, or something like it, around his encounter suit when they tried to attack him.

Comment: Most importantly Babylon 5 is not about technobabble. Your post is a false premise but a correct conclusion.   Vorlons and technomages have force fields. Also regular magnetic fields can suspend antimatter.  Surely the Shadows have almost anything that is technologically possible.  That said I have a vague recollection that there are claims of zero point energy being used by the first ones but that may be from the technomage trilogy which is severely out of continuity garbage.  Fusion generates plenty of energy regardless.

Comment: There was a kinda forcefield used in the first season the barrier created by Jason Ironheart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a word, **no.**

The terms "antimatter" and "anti-matter" aren't used in any of the [episode transcripts for Babylon 5](https://subslikescript.com/series/Babylon_5-105946), nor the spinoff movies or Crusade TV show.

It isn't used in any of the interviews on [Midwinter.com](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/lurker.html), nor does JMS use the term in any of the [AOL chats](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/ftp/Usenet/) that he did during the time it was airing.

Additionally, the [*licenced RPG*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylon_5_Roleplaying_Game) doesn't make any reference to anti-matter.